# Dynamic ID name in ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I have about 20 **asp:labels** in my ASP page, all with **ID="lbl#"**, where # ranges from 0 to 22. I want to dynamically change what they say. While I could write

```
lbl1.Text = "Text goes here"
```

for all 23 of them, I'd like to know if there is a way to loop through all of them and change their text.

I thought of creating an array with all my labels, and then just do a **For Each** loop, but I also have to check if the element exists with **IsNothing** before I change its text, so I got stuck there.

If anyone can help me, I'd really really appreciate it!

Thank you so so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically look up controls on the page by using the `System.Web.UI.Page.FindControl()` method in your Page_Load method:

```
Dim startIndex As Integer = 0
Dim stopIndex As Integer = 22

For index = startIndex To stopIndex
    Dim myLabel As Label = TryCast(FindControl("lbl" + index), Label)

    If myLabel Is Nothing Then
        Continue For
    End If

    myLabel.Text = "Text goes here"
Next
```

Comment: More efficient than mine, provided you always know how many there are (and you should start at 0).

Comment: Yeah, if he knows what the start and stop are, it works great.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so, so much!! And thank you StingyJack as well for your contribution! I'm probably going to use this technique a lot in the future :) THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, but you would likely need to tweak it (its from memory, so its not exactly 100% syntactically correct)

```
For Each _ctl as Control In Me.Controls()
  If (TypeOf(_ctl) Is Label) = False Then
    Continue For
  End If

  'add additional filter conditions'

  DirectCast(_ctl, Label).Text = "Text Goes Here"
Next
```

You can also do something similar on the client side using [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).